# Rasa custom actions events are lost

Tags: rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I'm trying to implement custom actions and have added action_get_answer to **domain.yml.**

```
actions:
 - utter_greet
 - utter_cheer_up
 - utter_did_that_help
 - utter_happy
 - utter_goodbye
 - actions.GetAnswer
```

Added the action in **actions.py** :

```
class GetAnswer(Action):

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_get_answer"


    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        dispatcher.utter_message("action_get_answer")

        return []
```

Ran the action server:

`$ rasa run actions`

Upon running rasa server :

`$ rasa x`

i get this error and `GetAnswer` is not triggered -

> ERROR rasa.core.processor - Encountered an exception while running
>   action 'action_get_answer'. Bot will continue, but the actions events
>   are lost. Make sure to fix the exception in your custom code.

How do I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on RASA X. I have created custom actions and it is successfully called. But first I want to know, does your stories.md file contain that action ? means when to call that action.
Here I am giving what I have implemented :

In stories.md file :-

```
## story1
* play
  - action_ask_question
```

In domain.yml file :-

```
...
actions:
- action_ask_question
...
```

In action.py file :-

```py
class ActionAskQuestion(Action):
     def name(self):
          return "action_ask_question"
     def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
          dispatcher.utter_message("Action called.")
          return []
```

If you have any question, comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error while using custom actions in Rasa (not Rasa X).
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrQn9.png)

I sloved the problem by adding action endpoints to endpoints.yml file

```
action_endpoint:
 url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"
```

run actions server using one command-line

```
rasa run actions
```

or (if you had not installed rasa)

```
python -m rasa_sdk --actions actions
```

and run rasa shell using another command-line (with endpoint configurations)

```
rasa shell --endpoints endpoints.yml
```